# Download File from Secure Sharepoint using Rest API - AudienceUriValidationFailedException

Tags: azure, rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I have been plunking away at trying to download a secure file from our company's secure Sharepoint.

I have performed the following steps, and I still receive a AudienceUriValidationFailedException when trying to download.

See below for my process.

I am in desperate need of some pointers. Did I miss a step? Am I forgetting something? Using the wrong client secret?

Thanks in advance!

- Batista

1. I created an app registration on the [Azure portal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzbSb.png)
2. I created a client secret under the [registered app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ3me.png)
3. I add the application to my company SharePoint using the "https://[COMPANY NAME]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx". I use the "Application (client) ID" string from the Azure app registration. I click the "Lookup" button, and the Title field [auto-populates.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMvzv.png)
4. I click "create", and then ["trust it"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEdPh.png)
5. Using postman, I used a post request to get an [access token.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFD2C.png)

- The content in red is taken from "Directory (tenat) ID"
- The orange is from "Application (client) ID"
- The green is from the "Value" column of the secret I created in step 2

6. I use the token it returns to download the file [from the SharePoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBIDL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error `AudienceUriValidationFailedException` occured as you generated access token for **Microsoft graph** and used it in running **SharePoint** requests.

To resolve the error, make use of below **Graph API** query to download file from site:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/drives/<doclib driveID>/root/children/<filename>
```

I have one document library with **`logo.jpg`** file in my SharePoint site like below:

[image]

To **download** this file via REST  API using bearer token, I registered one Azure AD application and added **`API permissions`** as below:

[image]

Now I generated **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appID
client_secret:secret
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

**Response:**

[image]

I used this token in running below Graph query and got file download link of **`logo.jpg`** in **response** like this:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/drives/<doclib driveID>/root/children/<filename>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran **downloadUrl** from response in browser, file downloaded successfully like below:

[image]

You can make use of below graph query to get ID of your site:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root:/sites/<sitename>
```

**Response:**

[image]

Similarly, you can use below query to get **drive ID** of document library:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID_from_above_response>/drives
```

**Response:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use Sharepoint REST API, in get token step use scope `https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com/.default`. This should fix your issue for the current configuration, and you'll be able to use Sharepoint REST API ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-net-server-csom-jsom-and-rest-api-index)).

But if you want to use Graph API (where scope is that one you have in screenshot in step 5) ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)), instead of step 3,4 you should add to your app registered in Azure AD > API Permissions > Application > Microsoft Graph API > select specific permissions you may need (`user.read, mail.read, file.readwrite` etc)

you may also use Delegated level of permissions, but in this case the way of get access token is different, not `client_credentials`