# API Sharepoint : List and download files with App Azure

Tags: azure, sharepoint, sharepoint-api, entra

I need to connect to a Sharepoint with API, download list of file from API and then download it.

I've tried to create App in Microsoft Entra and give it all rights with "sites.fullcontrol.all" But it doesn't work.

When I use `GetFolderByServerRelativePath()` I get this response :

```
{"error_description":"Exception of type 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AudienceUriValidationFailedException' was thrown."}
```

I am not sure which endpoint I've to use.

Can someone say me which endpoint use please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error **`AudienceUriValidationFailedException`** usually occurs if
> you are generating token with **Microsoft Graph** scope and using it for
> SharePoint API.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I used *GetFolderByServerRelativePath()* with token generated with MS Graph scope:

```
GET http://xxxxxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/site_name/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativePath(decodedUrl='Shared Documents/Test')
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to generate access token with either SharePoint scope(https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/.default) or switch to **Graph API** calls.

In my case, I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permissions** of Application type as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can use this token to call below Graph API query that **list files** along with download URL:

```http
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteID>/drives/<doclib driveID>/root/children/
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, click on that **download URLs** from response where files will be downloaded successfully like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[azure - Download File from Secure Sharepoint using Rest API - AudienceUriValidationFailedException - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76176010/download-file-from-secure-sharepoint-using-rest-api-audienceurivalidationfaile/76179453#76179453)