Reading Excel file returns 'Invalid Request' error
My goal is to use Python to read and write to an Excel file in SharePoint that other users will accessing.  I developed a solution to a problem on my local machine using Pandas to read and xlWings to write.  Now I'm trying to move it to SharePoint for others to use.
The solution is a non-computational application of Excel, it's essentialy to track positions of items so there will be many instances of many empty cells when the file is read.  I will need to read the range A1:V20, here's what the sheet looks like:

I tried various url changes based off Microsoft's guide here, but still can't get results.
Here are the permissions my application has:

I've read some tutorials/answers to questions (i.e. here and here) and can authenticate.  I've updated my url based off this answer, but no luck.
Here's the error message I am getting:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request"
    }
}
'value'

Previously I had the url ending in /workbook/tables('Plant_3') based off this answer but I was getting the following error:
"error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Open navigation properties are not supported on OpenTypes. Property name: 'tables'.",

I beleive that error was because my file has no tables and the url was trying to link to that object/collection.
Here's my code (updated per comments):
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

client_id = config['entra_auth']['client_id']
client_secret = config['entra_auth']['client_secret']
tenant_id = config['entra_auth']['tenant_id']

msal_scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
msal_app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client_id,
                                         authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
                                         client_credential=client_secret, )
result = msal_app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=msal_scope,
                                       account=None)
if not result:
    result = msal_app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=msal_scope)
if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']
else:
    raise Exception("Failed to acquire token")

headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
site_id = config['site']['site_id']  # https://www.powertechtips.com/check-site-id-sharepoint/
# https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-find-the-library-id-on-our-sharepoint/701e68f3-954f-490c-b3cb-ceb8bd5601d1
document_library_id = config['site']['document_library_id']
doc_id = config['site']['doc_id']  # from document details

# create url
url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{document_library_id}/items/{doc_id}:/workbook/worksheets('Plant_3')/range(address='A1:V20')"

# Make a GET request to the Microsoft Graph API to read the Excel file as a pandas dataframe
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
try:  # how I want it to go
    data = response.json().get("value", [])
    # if data found, convert to dataframe.
    if data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        print(df)
    else:
        print("No data")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")


Could you confirm whether your requirement is to retrieve excel file data via Graph API in python?

@Sridevi the file is stored in SharePoint (business) and I need to read and write to it.   Python is the language I know and Graph API is the only way I know that can access SharePoint.  I'm open to other solutions (using Python), but that's why I chose Graph.  So, not my requirement,  but I think it is a requirement forced upon my situation.

Future readers:  I had multiple issues, the answer was to one of them.  The other issues were self-inflicted by following answers online to parse ids from urls.  When I used Postman and walked through the answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76176010/download-file-from-secure-sharepoint-using-rest-api-audienceurivalidationfaile/76179453#76179453) to get the proper ids I was able to access my file.   Could not have figured it out without @Sridevi

I created one app registration and added same API permissions as you like this:

In SharePoint, I have one excel file named test.xlsx with below data:

Initially, I too got same error when I ran your code to retrieve above excel file data:

To resolve the error, I ran below modified python code and got the response with excel data successfully as below:
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests
import pandas as pd
import configparser

# Read the config file for credentials and details
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

client_id = config['entra_auth']['client_id']
client_secret = config['entra_auth']['client_secret']
tenant_id = config['entra_auth']['tenant_id']

# Set up Microsoft Graph authentication
msal_scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
msal_app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client_id,
                                         authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
                                         client_credential=client_secret)
result = msal_app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=msal_scope, account=None)
if not result:
    result = msal_app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=msal_scope)

if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']
else:
    raise Exception("Failed to acquire token")

# Prepare request headers with the acquired access token
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}

# Get necessary configuration data for the SharePoint file
site_id = config['site']['site_id'] 
document_library_id = config['site']['document_library_id']
doc_id = config['site']['doc_id']

# Use 'usedRange' to automatically detect the range with data
url = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{document_library_id}/items/{doc_id}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/usedRange"

# Make a GET request to Microsoft Graph API to read the worksheet range
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Extract only the 'values' part of the response
try:
    data = response.json().get('values', [])
    
    # If data is found, convert it to a pandas DataFrame and print it
    if data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])  # First row as column headers
        print(df)
    else:
        print("No data found.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

Response:

UPDATE:
For writing new data into excel file using Graph API in Python, I used below modified code and got response like this:
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication
import requests
import pandas as pd
import configparser
import json

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

client_id = config['entra_auth']['client_id']
client_secret = config['entra_auth']['client_secret']
tenant_id = config['entra_auth']['tenant_id']

msal_scope = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']
msal_app = ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id=client_id,
                                         authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}",
                                         client_credential=client_secret)
result = msal_app.acquire_token_silent(scopes=msal_scope, account=None)
if not result:
    result = msal_app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=msal_scope)

if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']
else:
    raise Exception("Failed to acquire token")

headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

site_id = config['site']['site_id'] 
document_library_id = config['site']['document_library_id']
doc_id = config['site']['doc_id']

# Define the new data you want to write (e.g., add new rows of data)
new_data = [
    ["Venkat", "8k"],
    ["Arko", "4k"]
]

body = {
    "values": new_data
}

# Here writing to A6:B7 -> 2 columns and 2 rows (Venkat and Arko)
url_write = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{document_library_id}/items/{doc_id}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='A6:B7')"

response_write = requests.patch(url_write, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(body))

if response_write.status_code == 200:
    print("Data successfully written to Excel.")
else:
    print(f"Error writing data: {response_write.text}")
    exit()

# Use 'usedRange' to automatically detect the range with data (including the newly added data)
url_read = f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{document_library_id}/items/{doc_id}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/usedRange"

response = requests.get(url_read, headers=headers)

try:
    data = response.json().get('values', [])
    
    # If data is found, convert it to a pandas DataFrame and print it
    if data:
        df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])  # First row as column headers
        print("Updated Excel Data:")
        print(df)
    else:
        print("No data found.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error while reading: {e}")

Response:


Tested this solution but I only get No Data, I wonder if my file is causing usedRange to fail.  I updated my question with the following based on this hunch: "The solution is a non-computational application of Excel, it's essentialy to track positions of items so there will be many instances of many empty cells when the file is read. I will need to read the range A1:V20"  Screenshot of file included in question to demonstrate what I'm describing.  Your effort to help me is greatly appreciated.

If you identified the range, try changing url_read parameter value to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/drives/{document_library_id}/items/{doc_id}/workbook/worksheets('Sheet1')/range(address='A1:V20').

Verified all id identifiers and they all look correct.  I tried changing the secret and I couldn't authenticate.  Copied and pasted my worksheet name directly from the file.  File is in .xlsx format if that matters.  Updated code in question to reflect my changes to it, almost identical to yours except my worksheet name is different. Can't think of what else to check, any ideas?

I added print(response) after the print("No data found.") statement, it's prints <Response [400]> so it's definately something I'm doing wrong.

Could you try running the code with identical Excel data and check if it works or not?

I added a new file called 'test.xlsx' and populated with the same data as your screenshot, and updated the document_id to match the new one.
I did not create a new site called DemoSite but will if you think it makes a difference.  print(response.text) says: {"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Invalid request","innerError":.  I suspect it's my url, here's the url when I am inside the Excel doc updating values: https://XYZco.sharepoint.com/sites/forge_furnace_movement/_layouts/15/doc.aspx?sourcedoc={some_id_key_I_have_removed}&action=edit.

I looked and the url you posted in the screenshot while inside the Excel document looks a lot different than mine.  That's surprising to me, I don't know why.  One difference may be my site set up as a Document Center and not a standard SharePoint site.

Working on GIF, will be posted soon.  In the meanting I replaced the document_id with the key in the sourcedoc={key} value and the error message changed to: "The provided drive id appears to be malformed, or does not represent a valid drive."

Created a GIF but SO won't let me post it in the question.  I will pursue the drive_id, I may have that wrong. I'm game to have a help session - that is a very generous offer and clearly you are a very talented person. IDK how to do that though.

What graph query you are running to get drive_id?

I'm working on that now, I found an online answer how to pull it out of a url, now I'm suspcious that's my problem.  I'm having a hard time finding the graph query I found posted online to do this so I'll find another.  Do you have a recommendation?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
